# How do I replace the values in a dataframe based on a lookup table in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to replace the placeholder values in my dataset with descriptions from a lookup table.

```
import pandas as pd

#Survey Data
df=pd.DataFrame({
                  'age':[653,653,654,653,653],
                  'cty':[1056,1056,1158,1158,1203],
                  'eth':[545,545,530,530,545]
                  })

    age  cty   eth
0   653  1056  NaN
1   653  1056  545
2   654  NaN   530
3   653  1158  530
4   653  1203  545

#Lookup table
lookup=pd.DataFrame({'category':['age', 'age', 'cty','cty', 'cty','eth','eth'], 
                     'value':[653,654,1056,1158,1203,545,530],
                     'description':['30 to 39','40 to 49','Belgium','Taiwan','Czech Republic',
                                     'White','Other']})

    category  value  description
0   age       653    30 to 39 
1   age       654    40 to 49
2   cty       1056   Belgium
3   cty       1158   Taiwan
4   cty       1203   Czech Republic
5   eth       545    White
6   eth       530    Other
```

So, each column in my dataset matches a category in the lookup table. I would like to go column by column, matching the category, and then the value, to replace the values with the appropriate description for each. So, it would look something like this:

```
    age        cty             eth
0   30 to 39   Belgium         NaN
1   30 to 39   Belgium         White
2   40 to 49   NaN             Other
3   30 to 39   Taiwan          Other
4   30 to 39   Czech Republic  White
```

Currently I'm working on building a solution using dictionaries for each column and mapping it, but that seems very clunky, and I have to create a separate dictionary for every category. Surely I should be able to lookup the category and then the value to replace the values?

Comment: ur lookup content for values is incomplete. 2 numbers short

Comment: Good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use pandas'  [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method : it will search for the keys in the dataframe and replace found keys with the associated values. your dataframe has a few missing NaNs, so I edited it to match what you posted

```
  #create a dictionary from the lookup
  repl = lookup.set_index('value')['description'].to_dict()

  #print(repl)
  
  {653: '30 to 39',
   654: '40 to 49', 
   1056: 'Belgium', 
   1158: 'Taiwan', 
   1203: 'Czech Republic',
   545: 'White', 
   530: 'Other'}

  #pass it using pandas' replace method
  df.replace(repl)

  
      age         cty            eth
0   30 to 39    Belgium          NaN
1   30 to 39    Belgium          White
2   40 to 49    NaN               Other
3   30 to 39    Taiwan           Other
4   30 to 39    Czech Republic  White
```